# Unable to verify stripe payment correctly in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

so I just noticed I had a small problem. I'm using [Stripe](http://stripe.com) as my payment processor, and what happened was quite simple. I had a bug in my code which didn't allow me to save the `customer_id_token` and change a boolean called `subscription active`.

However the payment still went through (confirmed in stripe logs). Thus it's obvious I don't have proper validations in place as this should never happen. Here's what my code looks like now:

```
def create
  customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
    :email => current_user.email,
    :plan => params[:plan_id],
    :card  => params[:stripeToken]
  )
  current_user.update_attributes!(
    :stripe_customer_token => customer.id,
    :subscription_active => true,
    :plan_id => params[:plan_id]
  )
  redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Successfully subscribed'
  rescue Stripe::CardError => e
    flash[:error] = e.message
    redirect_to charges_path
end
```

I can see that they are obviously not really connected with one another, and my question is how can I turn this into something that if the `customer_token` is *not* saved it won't go through with the payment either?

Comment: transactions?  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html

Comment: interesting wasn't aware of this, I'm not entirely sure how to rewrite this into this kind of syntax, would you be able to get me started - and I'll be forever grateful!

Answer (score 0):

Okay,

I'm going to take a shot at this, problem is I do not know how Stripe works, so I cannot guarantee this to work.
I just want to demonstrate the usage of transactions:

```
def create
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
      email: current_user.email,
      plan: params[:plan_id],
      card: params[:stripeToken]
    )
    current_user.update_attributes!(
      stripe_customer_token: customer.id,
      subscription_active: true,
      plan_id: params[:plan_id]
    )
  end

  redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Successfully subscribed'
rescue Stripe::CardError => e
  flash[:error] = e.message
  redirect_to charges_path
end
```

What I would definitely add to your current_user model, is a validation to check that the token cannot be null:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :stripe_customer_token, presence: true
end
```

That way the update fails when the token is not provided, rolling back the transaction. Although with this it should also work if the first call fails.

However this will only work if this Stripe::Customer supports transactions. I do not know or gurantee this to be the solution.
If the Customer call still goes through and does not validate whether the payment is valid, then there's not much you can do.